# How is it possible to use a nightly rustc compiler in buildroot

Tags: rust, buildroot

rustc and cargo are supported in buildroot. But even the latest buildroot master uses rust version 1.33.0 stable I think.

How can I use the a nightly version of rust in buildroot?

**Update**: This patch http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2016-April/159523.html introduces rust in buildroot. And this buildroot repo https://github.com/elebihan/buildroot/tree/feature/rust-1.33.0 has some latest rustc version.

Answer (score 1):

This is for a QEMU ARM Vexpress, but I think it will get you where you are going:

- [Using Rust with Buildroot (full build)](http://www.elebihan.com/posts/using-rust-with-buildroot-full-build.html)

You can skip up to the `pushd` command to the downloaded nightly rust source. Instead of doing all that, just use the location of the code you got when you run `rustup install nightly` (or however else you're installing the nightly snapshot`).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the build commands don't need to be changed, you can just download the source to some directory and add `RUST_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR=<path to rust source>` in your local.mk. See [the Buildroot manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_using_buildroot_during_development).